# How can I put the below java query in switch case?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, switch-statement

// How can I put the below java query in switch case? I am working with spring-mobile project and I need to put the below code in switch help.

```
try {
    if (device.isMobile()) {
        redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getMobile_success_redirect_url();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getMobile_failure_redirect_url();
    logger.error("Failed to verify email. Cause: {}", ex);
}
try {
    if (device.isTablet()) {
        redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getTablet_success_redirect_url();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getTablet_success_redirect_url();
    logger.error("Failed to verify email. Cause: {}", ex);
}
try {
    if (device.isNormal()) {
        redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getWeb_success_redirect_url();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    redirectUri = cfg.getEmail().getVerification().getWeb_failure_redirect_url();
    logger.error("Failed to verify email. Cause: {}", ex);
}

response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
```

Comment: It looks fine like it is. Why use a switch?

Comment: You can use an enum attribute within `Device` class instead of all those boolean flags which could be defined as `enum DeviceType { MOBILE, TABLET, NORMAL}` and then it might just make sense to have a `redirectUri` mapping per type. (even using `switch`). This implies that only one type of device is feasible for a device entity though to note.

Comment: In your code, the cases are not mutual exclusive, as even when one test succeeded, the other tests are still executed and their clauses may overwrite an already existing result. That’s not how switch works. But if you actually want mutual exclusive behavior, 90% of this code is redundant and can be removed, even without changing the `if` statements to a different syntactical construct. However, there’s one thing that is not clear: how is the exception handling supposed to work, when it repeats the very operation that just failed with an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comment by @Naman. I agree, here are a few more details.

I am not sure if the class of type `device` is in your control.

But if it is, you should perhaps have field denoting device type, which can be an Enum with 3 values `MOBILE, TABLET, NORMAL`.

Now you can have a switch case on this `Enum` with each case containing code for that specific use case.

The method for this switch case should accept 2 params, the newly created `DeviceType` enum and the Object that is returned by `cfg.getEmail().getVerification()`.

Rough outline but I hope you get the point.

`String getRedirectUri(DeviceType deviceType, Verification verification) {
    switch(deviceType) {
        case TABLET:
        case MOBILE:
        case NORMAL:
        default
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you. I did the same way.

Comment: As a side note, you should perhaps also do required validation for cfg.getEmail().getVerification() so that you don't get a NPE

Comment: The values are being picked from properties file.